# Mongoose mapReduce emit function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mapreduce

According to [mongodb's documents](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) and [mongoose's document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.mapReduce), I found a global function called `emit` which is not a standard build-in javascript function, but it just works. I'm wondering why it works and where does it define?

I guess is that mongoose pass `o.map.toString()` to native mongodb driver. Is it right?

Thanks.